# Set featured image for video thumbnail automaticlly

Tags: video-player

I have a lot of post in my site
each one has feature image and embeds video
could I set all featured images for video thumbnail automatically, via the function or something else?

Comment: And what is video thumbnail? Do you want to generate image from video, or do you already have these images generated?

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż I want to use feature thumbnail.
by the way video hosted on another server. I just copy their link to my posts